# Ways to infer type to generic function

Tags: swift, generics, types

How can I infer a type to a generic function other than like this:

`let a: MyType = genericFunction()`

or these casts:

`let a = MyType(genericFunction())`

`let a = genericFunction() as MyType`

A conditional cast doesn’t infer the type:

`let a = genericFunction() as? MyType`

What else does?

UPDATE:

As Victor Pro assumed the function should return a generic type. It could look like:

```
func genericFunction<T>() -> T {
}
```

Comment: Could you post the declaration of genericFunction?

Comment: I updated the question with the declaration `func genericFunction<T>() -> T {}`.

Comment: Then why do you need any other way than the first?

Comment: I want to learn Swift. I also want to have an open mind. I want to go deep. I want to learn about my options. I want to expand and better myself.

Comment: That didn't answer my question really. Anyway, I personally think that your first variant is much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed. I didn’t ask for the best way to infer the type though. So, the accepted answer is a vaild answer. It also is the only one right now. So, it is only fair to accept it. It also helped me understand Swift. I might be able to use it one way or another in the future. I am very grateful for this answer.

Comment: Oh! And my variant only works for this specific example. If I want to use the return value of `genericFunction()` in a expression, I would need one of the other variants or the variant in the accepted answer. `let a = MyType(genericFunction()) + b` (given that the + operator here returns something other than `MyType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `genericFunction()` has a generic return type. Then, another way to infer the type is to pass it as an argument to the function: `func genericFunction<T>(returnType: T.Type) -> T {...}`. You can call it now via e.g. `let val = genericFunction(String.self)`, whereby `val` is of type `String`.